# Formatting Chapter in report

Tags: formatting

[image: Chapter formatting]

I want similar formatting as shown in the image. Any idea how I can achieve similar formatting especially the number 1 and the black rectangle box. Many thanks.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) On this site, a question should typically revolve around an abstract issue (e.g. "How do I get a double horizontal line in a table?") rather than a concrete application (e.g. "How do I make this table?"). Questions that look like "Please do this complicated thing for me" tend to get closed because they are either "off topic", "too broad", or "unclear". Please try to make your question clear and simple by giving a [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228): you'll stand a greater chance of getting help.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for the tip. I will try to be more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `memoir` class and the `veelo` chapterstyle. (`< texdoc memoir` *Chapter headings*). The `memoir` class encompasses both the `book` and `report` classes.

```
\documentclass[...]{memoir}
...
\chapterstyle{veelo}
...
\begin{document}
...
\chapter{A chapter}
...
\end{document}
```